# Java - Select all item in the menu

Tags: java, swing

I'm using the `javax.swing` library, and I try to solve this problem:

I have a `MenuBar` in which I created `JMenu`, this menu has `JCheckBoxMenuItem` items. Like this:

```
//creating objects:

jMenuBar = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
jMenuAlgorithms = new javax.swing.JMenu();
jCheckBoxSPEA = new javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem();
jCheckBoxNSGAII = new javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem();
jSeparator1 = new javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator();
jCheckBoxMenuEnableAll = new javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem();
jCheckBoxMenuDisableAll = new javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem();

//settings and putting them together:
jCheckBoxSPEA.setSelected(true);
jCheckBoxSPEA.setText("SPEA");
jMenuAlgorithms.add(jCheckBoxSPEA);

jCheckBoxNSGAII.setSelected(true);
jCheckBoxNSGAII.setText("NSGAII");
jMenuAlgorithms.add(jCheckBoxNSGAII);
jMenuAlgorithms.add(jSeparator1);

jCheckBoxMenuEnableAll.setSelected(true);
jCheckBoxMenuEnableAll.setText("Enable all");
jCheckBoxMenuEnableAll.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            jCheckBoxMenuEnableAllMouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });
jMenuAlgorithms.add(jCheckBoxMenuEnableAll);

jCheckBoxMenuDisableAll.setText("Disable all");
jMenuAlgorithms.add(jCheckBoxMenuDisableAll);

jMenuBar.add(jMenuAlgorithms);
```

If the user selects `jCheckBoxMenuEnableAll` item, I would like to select all the items above the separator. If he selects `jCheckBoxMenuDisableAll`, I would like to deselect all the items above the separator.

As you can see, I've added `mouseClicked` action to the `jCheckBoxMenuEnableAll` item. Now, I would like to do something like this:

```
private void jCheckBoxMenuEnableAllMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {  

    for(JCheckBoxMenuItem item : jMenuAlgorithms){
        item.setSelected(true);
    } 
    //deselect then jCheckBoxMenuDisableAll, it's not essential for instance
}
```

But apparently, I can't do the for loop like this, as the menu item isn't an `array` or `Iterable`.

Well, just for testing, I had done something very stupid (code below) - I pass all the items in the menu, and if the item is a check box, I make its copy, set ist value to "true" (selected) and then replace the original item by its copy. Very stupid, I know and I absolutely don't want to do like this, however, I didn't find another way to do it. I just wanted to see if this would work. I supposed it should, but it stoll doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? Thank you very, very much for your time.

```
private void jCheckBoxMenuEnableAllMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                                    

    if(jCheckBoxMenuEnableAll.isSelected()){
        for(int i =0; i< jMenuAlgorithms.getItemCount(); i++){ //for all items in the menu, separators included
           if(jMenuAlgorithms.getItem(i) instanceof JCheckBoxMenuItem){
               JCheckBoxMenuItem item = ((JCheckBoxMenuItem)jMenuAlgorithms.getItem(i));
               item.setSelected(true);
               jMenuAlgorithms.insert(item, i);
           } 
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I think [JPopupMenu#getSubElements()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JPopupMenu.html#getSubElements--) is what you are looking for.

  - see also: [JMenu#getSubElements()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenu.html#getSubElements--)

    > Returns an array of MenuElements containing the submenu for this menu
    >   component. If popup menu is null returns an empty array. This method
    >   is required to conform to the MenuElement interface. Note that since
    >   JSeparators do not conform to the MenuElement interface, this array
    >   will only contain JMenuItems.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MenuSubElementsTest {
  public JComponent makeUI() {
    JMenu jMenuAlgorithms = new JMenu("MenuAlgorithms");

    JMenuItem jCheckBoxMenuEnableAll = new JMenuItem("Enable all");
    jCheckBoxMenuEnableAll.addActionListener(e -> {
      for (MenuElement me: jMenuAlgorithms.getPopupMenu().getSubElements()) {
        System.out.println("debug1: " + me.getClass().getName());
        if (me instanceof JCheckBoxMenuItem) {
          ((JCheckBoxMenuItem) me).setSelected(true);
        }
      }
      //or: getJCheckBoxMenuItem(jMenuAlgorithms).forEach(r -> r.setSelected(true));
    });

    JMenuItem jCheckBoxMenuDisableAll = new JMenuItem("Disable all");
    jCheckBoxMenuDisableAll.addActionListener(e -> {
      getJCheckBoxMenuItem(jMenuAlgorithms).forEach(r -> r.setSelected(false));
    });

    jMenuAlgorithms.add(new JCheckBoxMenuItem("SPEA", true));
    jMenuAlgorithms.add(new JCheckBoxMenuItem("NSGAII", true));
    jMenuAlgorithms.addSeparator();
    jMenuAlgorithms.add(jCheckBoxMenuEnableAll);
    jMenuAlgorithms.add(jCheckBoxMenuDisableAll);

    JMenuBar jMenuBar = new JMenuBar();
    jMenuBar.add(jMenuAlgorithms);

    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    p.add(jMenuBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    return p;
  }
  private static Stream<JCheckBoxMenuItem> getJCheckBoxMenuItem(MenuElement p) {
    Class<JCheckBoxMenuItem> clz = JCheckBoxMenuItem.class;
    return stream(p).filter(clz::isInstance).map(clz::cast);
  }
//   public static Stream<MenuElement> stream(MenuElement p) {
//     return Arrays.stream(p.getSubElements())
//       .map(MenuSubElementsTest::stream).reduce(Stream.of(p), Stream::concat);
//   }
  public static Stream<MenuElement> stream(MenuElement p) {
    return Stream.concat(Stream.of(p), Arrays.stream(p.getSubElements())
      .peek(me -> System.out.println("debug2: " + me.getClass().getName()))
      .flatMap(MenuSubElementsTest::stream));
  }
  public static void main(String... args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      JFrame f = new JFrame();
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.getContentPane().add(new MenuSubElementsTest().makeUI());
      f.setSize(320, 240);
      f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      f.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}
```